# How does Javascript callback use external variabile that has to be still created

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to nodejs, I've come across this function in express

```
var server = app.listen(()=>{
    console.log(server.address())
})
```

How does the callback use the returned object from the listen function, can someone explain me the mechanism behind this code? Thanks

Comment: `app.listen` returns, and only some time later after the server is ready, the callback is called.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it helps to rewrite the code into the following equivalent code:

```js
var server;
function logServerAddress() {
  console.log(server.address());
}
server = app.listen(logServerAddress);
```